# Sort a string property that is in a List(of class)

Tags: vb.net

In my database project, the user should have a search function.
The search results are saved in a `List(of Class_Post)`. This list should now be sorted alphabetically.
I would like to add that I could already have used:
`sorted.Sort(Function(x, y) x.compareto(y))`
But the FxCopAnalyzer complained that the sorting could differ due to regional settings, so I now want to use `String.Compare (x, y, StringComparison.Ordinal)`.

**The property to be sorted is Class_Post.Ueberschrift**. The error is at line 11 (sorted.sort(comparison)): *Overload resolution failed because no accessible "Sort" can be called with these arguments:
"Public Overloads Sub Sort (comparer As IComparer (Of Class_Post))": "Option Strict On" does not allow implicit conversions from "Comparison (Of String)" to "IComparer (Of Class_Post)".*

```
Dim sorted As List(Of Class_Post) = Ergebnisse.ToList()

        Select Case Suchmoeglichkeit
            Case Sortiermoeglichkeiten.Alphabetisch ' alphabetical (a String)

                Dim comparison As Comparison(Of String) =
                        Function(x, y)
                            Dim rslt As Integer = x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length)
                            Return rslt
                        End Function
                sorted.Sort(comparison)

            Case Sortiermoeglichkeiten.Erstellzeit 'Creation Time (a Date)
                sorted.Sort(Function(x, y) x.Erstelldatum_dieses_Posts.CompareTo(y.Erstelldatum_dieses_Posts))
            Case Else
                Exit Select
        End Select

        Return sorted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want a `Comparison(Of String)` but a `Comparison(Of Class_Post)` and you want to compare the `Ueberschrift`.

```
Case Sortiermoeglichkeiten.Alphabetisch ' alphabetical (a String)
        Dim comparison As Comparison(Of Class_Post) =
                Function(x, y)
                    Dim rslt As Integer = StringComparer.Ordinal.Compare(x.Ueberschrift, y.Ueberschrift)
                    Return rslt
                End Function
        sorted.Sort(comparison)
```

A `ListOf(Of Class_Post)` can just be sorted with a `Comparison(Of Class_Post)`.

Another approach which is easier to read and to maintain is LINQ:

```
Select Case Suchmoeglichkeit
    Case Sortiermoeglichkeiten.Alphabetisch ' alphabetical (a String)
        Return Ergebnisse.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Ueberschrift).ToList()
    Case Sortiermoeglichkeiten.Erstellzeit 'Creation Time (a Date)
        Return Ergebnisse.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Erstelldatum_dieses_Posts).ToList()
    Case Else
        Exit Select
End Select
```

Comment: I wouldn't consider those two options interchangeable in all cases. The first option sorts the existing list in-place while the LINQ option creates a new list, meaning that any existing references to the original list will still see the data unsorted. It won't matter in many cases but it's important to understand in case you have a scenario where it does matter.

Comment: @jmcilhinney; But OP is creating a new `List(Of Class_Post)` at the beginning of that method anyway, `Ergebnisse` is the original query or collection. So in this case it's interchangeable. Also in most other cases it doesn't matter if you get a new collection or keep the same. But i agree, that's a difference.